# add item to key in registry with vb or c# AND get Administrative Access

Tags: c#, windows, key, registry, user-administration

I want add item to a key in registry and find "CreateSubKey" command but point is this command create sub key not item to a key. for example path of "Computer\HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International" has about 40 item and 3 sub key. I want add item to "\International" not sub key.

another problem is that when I want add subkey to another users in "Computer\HKEY_USERS" path ,I got error "cant access other user registry" .how could I handle that with code without login as admin in windows?

LOOK AT PICTURE: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PwpG.png)
best regards.

Answer (score 0):

1. 

Create the key you are interested in and then [set the values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.setvalue):

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.Users.CreateSubKey("DEFAULT\\Control Panel\\International");
rk.SetValue("a number", 42);
rk.SetValue("my string", "fiftythree");
```

2. 

You have to be elevated administrator to modify keys in roots other than CurrentUser. Normal users are not allowed to modify machine settings nor the settings of other users.

Comment: Plz look at picture added .do you think subkey is it work for #2 ???  i think it just add key to #1 not add item to #2

Comment: `SetValue` sets a value in pane #2. You picture shows CurrentUser root key but your question asked about Users, make sure you are using the correct root.

Comment: if i Want add a new value to pane#2 doyou think set value could add item that ?

Comment: Yes, that method will create/modify values in pane #2